# distribution of quadratic form of jointly normal random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random-matrices

I need to derive the distribution of the random variable
$\frac{W'(I-1(1'1)^{-1}1')ZZ'(I-1(1'1)^{-1}1')W} {Z'(I-1(1'1)^{-1}1')Z}$
, where $(Z, W)'$ ~ $N(0, I), \,Z=(Z_{1}, ..., Z_{n}), \,W=(W_{1}, ..., W_{n})$

It is too difficult for me to solve. Is there anyone who can give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: Where is your effort? Have you heard of Wishart distribution?